# How to create a Youtube player for Google Cardboard

Tags: android, video, youtube

I want to create a Youtube video player for android so that I can use it with [Google Cardboard](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/). Right now I have no idea how to go about doing this. I am familiar with both Unity and Android Studio but I need guidance in how to play a youtube video within my app. The [Cardboard App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo&hl=en) has a youtube feature in it, but the voice search function is horrible and I never get the correct video I want. I would like it to be like the youtube feature within the cardboard app, with head tracking, etc... Any help appreciated!